# Java - Read lines of file into different variables

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

I've worked with Java for a few years but during that time I've almost never had to do anything with text files.  I need to know how to read lines of a text file into different variables as two-digit integers, along with several lines of said text file into a 2D integer array.  Every text file is to be written like this:

```
5 5
1 2
4 3
2 4 2 1 4
0 1 2 3 5
2 0 4 4 1
2 5 5 3 2
4 3 3 2 1
```

The first three lines should all be separate integers, but the first line is indicative of the 2D array's dimensions.  The last segment needs to go into that integer array.  This is what I've  got so far in terms of code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Asst1Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("small.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        while(x.hasNext()){

        }
    }
}
```

I'm completely at a loss of how to do this.

Comment: If you've used Java for a few years, you should be comfortable with javadoc: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html and know there is an official Java tutorial explaining almost every Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Comment: Why don't you write down the steps you would take as a human trying to accomplish this task. I'll start you off with number 1: Read the first line. Separate the two integers. The first one is the number rows, the  second one is the number of columns. What the the second and third rows supposed to represent anyway?

Comment: The second and third rows indicate a start and end position within the array.  It's supposed to represent a map.

Comment: **1.** Declare `x` outside the `try-catch`. **2.** Read the documentation for [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) and [hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29). **3.** Learn to create and use mutli-dimensional arrays. **4.** Learn to use nested `for` loops.

Comment: I know how to use for loops and multi-dimensional arrays but I'm thinking that if I try reading this with the x.nextInt() I'm going to wind up with incorrect results.

Comment: @user3308219, calls to `nextInt()` will give you the numbers 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, ..., 3, 2, 1 in this order. Just make sure you use them in the correct order (i.e. store first two in dimensions, store next two in location, next two wherever, and then run the nested for-loop with the outer one reading down the rows and the inner one reading across the columns).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedoish code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("blammo.txt"));

List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
String line1;
String line2;
String line3;

line1 = readALine(input);
line2 = readALine(input);
line3 = readALine(input);

... process the lines as you see fit.  perhaps String.split(line1);

while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    String current = input.nextLine();
    data.add(current);
}

private String readALine(final Scanner input)
{
    String returnValue;

    if (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        returnValue = input.nextLine();
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = null; // maybe throw an exception instead.
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Once you have the data (or perhaps while reading it), you can split it and process it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an `ArrayList` of integer arrays instead. It'll be easier to do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] parts = line.split("[\\s]");
Integer[] pArray = new Integer[parts.length];
for (Integer x = 0; x < parts.length; x++) {
    pArray[x] = Integer.parseInt(parts[x]);
}
list.add(pArray);
```

Do the bulk of that inside of a loop obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full version.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Asst1Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("small.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            return;
        }
        int rows = in.nextInt();
        int cols = in.nextInt();
        int startRow = in.nextInt();
        int startCol = in.nextInt();
        int endRow = in.nextInt();
        int endCol = in.nextInt();
        int[][] map = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                map[row][col] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's throwing the exception even though the text file and the Asst1Main file should be in the same directory.  It puts small.txt outside of the default package so I don't know if this has any bearing on the situation.

Comment: The file small.txt should be in the working directory, which is the directory from which you run your class. Use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to print the working directory.

Comment: Perfect, now it works.  I thought the .txt files all had to be under src with Eclipse, but it seems that they need to be stored under the Java project root folder.  Anyway, thanks for the assistance.